# Use Stack Overflow profile email address for Stack Overflow Careers generated resume instead of OpenID

Tags: feature-request, status-norepro, stack-overflow-jobs

On Stack Overflow Careers, the `create pdf` and `create markdown` buttons can be used to generate a resume from your Careers profile. However, except for the option of turning it on or off, there appears to be no way of configuring what email address actually appears on the resume. It simply uses the email address associated with your Stack Exchange OpenID.

I would like to propose that the email address used on the exported Careers resume use the email address specified on your Stack Overflow profile instead of the OpenID, either optionally or by default if one has been specified.

Editing a PDF isn't the hardest thing in the world to do, but when applying for jobs, I use a different email address from my personal address which is associated with my Stack Exchange OpenID, and I imagine many other people do as well.

If for any reason this functionality is not possible, an option to manually enter an email address would also work.

Comment: I worked around this by just creating and associating a new OpenID with my careers account. It's not ideal, but it got the hob done when I needed it.

Comment: I second this.  Recruiters tend to spam mercilessly.  If my SO Careers account _came with_ an e-mail address that could be included in the resume, even if all it did was forward any e-mails sent to it to a nominated address of my choice, that would be awesome.  Bonus points if the provided address permutes automatically every time the resume is exported, so that I can know what version of my resume a person is responding to.  And super extra bonus points if SO Careers automatically correlates a message with the corresponding resume version before forwarding it on to me.

Comment: And also if I could shut off or redirect messages being sent to any particular permutation of the provided proxy address at any time (in case some revision of my resume falls into the hands of a particularly spam-happy recruiter, or if I'm just plain not interested in employment-related e-mails for a time), that would be perfect.  There's some potential for analytics as well, such as tracking which revision of a resume receives the strongest response to guide subsequent edits, etc..

Comment: -1 In order to submit a valid application you need to be able to decompress a pdf and manually edit its code. </satire>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I'm posting this as a Careers user, not as a Stack Exchange employee. In particular, I'm not in the Careers team, so don't treat my answer as gospel. :-)*

I've been able to change the email address in my Careers profile itself:

[image: Careers email address field]

In my testing, changing this was enough to make the PDF and Markdown exports show the correct email.

Comment: Wow. Don't mind me then. I guess I just went blind for a second.